# react native error when opening realm on more than one screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I am having a question regarding the creation and use of the realm database in react-native.

I have two screens, responsible for performing operations such as crud, category.js and client.js

In the **category.js** I have the following constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    realm = new Realm({
        schema: [{ name: 'category', primaryKey: 'id', properties: { id: 'int', descricao: 'string', status: 'bool' } }]
    })
}
```

and in **cliente.js** I have

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    realm = new Realm({
        schema: [{ name: 'client', primaryKey: 'id', properties: { id: 'int', nome: 'string', cpf: 'string', celular: 'string', status: 'bool' } }]
    })
}
```

Now I have the following doubts.

with this schema in question, do I have a database where I have the tables categories and clients?

when I'm on the client.js screen and I want to go to category.js I get informed the error of: already opened on current thread with different schema.

how can I close the connection or open, so that I can use the realm on both screens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not opening `realm` on a new screen you are trying to creating a new instance. This is why you are having issues. You should only have one instance of `realm` in your application.

1. Create a single file where you import the `realm` dependency.
2. Create all the schema that you need in this file.
3. Create a `new Realm()` instance and add your schema to it
4. Export the new instance of `realm`.
5. Instead of using `realm` in your components use your instance of `realm` that you just created.

## `realm.js`

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class Category extends Realm.Object {}
Category.schema = {
  name: 'category',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    descricao: 'string',
    status: 'bool'
  }
};

class Client extends Realm.Object {}
Client.schema = {
  name: 'client',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    nome: 'string',
    cpf: 'string',
    celular: 'string',
    status: 'bool'
  }
};

const RealmInstance = new Realm({ schema: [Category, Client] });
export default RealmInstance;
```

Then you should be able to import it in the following way

```
import realm from './path/to/realm.js'
```

You can see how `realm` do it by looking at their [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/tree/master/examples/ReactExample).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, thanks to your answer I was able to solve my problem. thank you